How to include images in the build of a Wordpress multi block plugin?
My WP plugin should show some (default) images in the font-end and editor UI. However, the URL generated with my code, refers to the build folder, while the images are not.
This is my structure:
screenprint of the project structure
lucy-recipe-blocks
-build
-src
--images
---meal-type-dinner.png
--blocks
---lucy-meal-type-block
----block.json
----edit.js
----index.js
----render.php
----save.js
-webpack.config.js
-lucy-recipe-blocks.php
-package.json

This is the code in render.php:
<?php
  // $image_url = esc_url('/wp-content/plugins/lucy-recipe-blocks/src/images/meal-type-dinner.jpg');
  $image_url = esc_url(plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'images/meal-type-dinner.jpg');
  $alt_text = esc_attr('Meal type image');
  $category_title = esc_html('Meal Type Name');
?>

<button class="lucy-meal-type">
  <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text; ?>" class="lucy-meal-type__image">
  <div class="lucy-meal-type__namespace">
    <label class="lucy-meal-type__text"><?php echo $category_title; ?></label>
  </div>
</button>

This is the webpack.config.js content:
const path = require('path');

module. Exports = {
  entry: {
    'lucy-meal-type-block': './src/blocks/lucy-meal-type-block/index.js',
    // Add more blocks as needed
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]/index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/blocks'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/',
              publicPath: '../images/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};

But the build gives errors:
  ./src/blocks/lucy-meal-type-block/style.scss 620 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
  ./src/blocks/lucy-meal-type-block/edit.js 1.24 KiB [built] [code generated] [1 error]
  ./src/blocks/lucy-meal-type-block/save.js 802 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

When using a static URL (commented out in the code shown) and I remove the webpack.config.js, it works. When I manually copy the image and folder to the build, it works with the dynamic link code. But that is obviously not desired.
I know I`m missing something obvious here....but what? Does it have to do with the fact I'm working with a multi block plugin setup? I would really appreciate feedback.

still struggling with this issue. can't find the solution in the WP documentation, here on stackoverflow, git copilot or any other resource I know. if I'm taking a fundamentally wrong approach, let me know as well. that's the only way I can improve. thanks in advance!
